# Recreate NSTimer?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, nstimer

I invalidate my NSTimer like this (as defined in my .h)

```
if(myTimer2 != nil) { 
[myTimer2 invalidate];
myTimer2 = nil;
}
```

Now how will I reshow it (by using the same name)?

Thanks. 
Coulton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming myTimer2 is a retained property:

```
if(myTimer2 != nil) { 
      [myTimer2 invalidate];
      self.myTimer2 = nil;
}
self.myTimer2 = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval....];
```

Answer (score 1):

Two quick remarks on your `if` statement:

1. the `!= nil` is redundant: Objective C is C (and then some...), which means that everything that evaluates to `0` has the meaning of a boolean 'NO'.
2. In Objecive C, messaging `nil`is perfectly valid. So in this case, there is very little benefit from performing this check.

Now, to answer your question:
You recreate the timer just like you set it up for the first time.

Ideally, (since you seem to need to repeatedly do so) you have factored the setup of the timer out to a separate method. So all you need to do is call that method again.